# How to check Facetime Support in iOS devices (hardware check)

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-4, ipad-2, facetime

I want to check if iOS device I am using has support for Facetime call. I don't want to check the iOS version on the device, rather if the device has the hardware support to initiate a Facetime call.

For example: I have an iPad 1 with iOS version 4.0 and above, but if I don't have a camera (or a front camera), the Facetime call should not initiate. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `canOpenUrl` method with FaceTime scheme, as follows:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"facetime://5555555555"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

you could check if the device responds to hasTorch

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]; 
if ([device hasTorch]) { 
//do stuff
}
```

this way you know they can handle facetime, so maybe show an alert asking them to ensure facetime is enable before initiating a call?

Comment: what about in iPad without flashLight.. any idea on how to check in this case