# Check if facetime is enabled on the device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facetime

The app we're building has a simple button that starts a facetime session with a specific number. No biggee here.

I use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"facetime://5555555555"]];
```

to check if the device is capable of facetime calls. Again, this works fine.

But a user can turn facetime on/off through the settings screen of his device.
When facetime is turned off the above `canOpenURL` method still returns `YES` even though facetime is disabled. And when I start a new session through the `openURL` method the screen simply goes to my contactlist without starting a facetime session.

Anyone know if it's possible to determine if facetime is enabled on the device.

Comment: Doesn't look possible right now. duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631921/is-there-any-facetime-api-for-iphone-developers

Comment: A bit duplicate, that question is more focussed on the API itself. I only need to 'get' some device settings. Not an entire API

Comment: How about this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516188/how-to-check-facetime-support-in-ios-devices-harware-check

Comment: @ScottCorscadden: That's exactly what I do, see my post

Comment: Ah - my bad. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way that you can detect if FaceTime has been enabled or disabled (as of iOS 5.1). Sorry.

As for...

```
facetime://5555555555
```

...according to [this Apple Developer forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/629980) post, Apple rejects apps that uses undocumented APIs, and FaceTime is one of them. Look at the fourth post.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) is the link that the person was talking about.

There is probably another way around it, but I can't think of anything right now. Hopes this helps answer your question.