# Check programmatically if contact allows FaceTime in Objective-C or Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, facetime

Just like the title states, I am working on contacts app. What I would like to know is if there is a way for me to find out if the contacts are reachable through FaceTime? Is there a public API for it? (Note: Solutions like ChatKit.framework for iMessage are not really acceptable, i.e. private APIs)

**UPDATE:**  found a post here, that partially answers the question: [FaceTime programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888946/check-if-facetime-is-enabled-on-the-device)

**UPDATE #2:**  using @"//facetime:" scheme does not seem to work at all, as I always get **true** in return

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "facetime://0000000000")!)
```